# Sanitize vimeo embed code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitization

Here's the vimeo url code.

```
<object width="40" height="300"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param   name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=9082619&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=9082619&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="40" height="300"></embed></object><p><a href="http://vimeo.com/9082619">Queueing - One in a Dozen</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/enki">sideshow bob</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Here's the example from the Rails docs

```
  <%= sanitize @app.description, 
  :tags => %w(table tr td), 
  :attributes => %w(id class styles) %>
```

I want to just show the video, no height, width, title etc. I tried modifying it for the past 20 mins, but couldn't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what exactly you're trying to do, but try:

```
<%= sanitize @app.description,
 :tags => %w(a embed object p param),
 :attributes => %w(allowfullscreen allowscriptaccess href name src type value) %>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I trying to do. Thanks